# Can the blog formatting be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, blog

I don't know how to contact the administrators of the tex-talk blog (which used to be the TeX blog on this network before that got closed down), but in the transfer from the SE network it would appear that the formatting of some old posts has been lost.

Specifically (but I suspect not uniquely), [this old post](http://tex-talk.net/2011/08/do-the-knuth-shuffle/) shows the raw markdown instead of the formatted output.

Comment: Click on *About* in the top bar, scroll down to *Discussing the blog* and visit the blog chat room. Or ping Stefan in our chat here on site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you! I fixed the post. It was actually just opening and saving, since the markdown plugin is installed but the imported post needed applying it. In addition I adjusted to GeSHi syntax highlighting.

I will look through the other posts. I went through them after the transfer but it seems that I did not complete that yet.

Thanks again for that notice!

PS: further posts already found and fixed, such as [I TeX Therefore I Toast](http://tex-talk.net/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/). Luckily I can let wordpress search for markdown keywords to find untouched markdown posts.

Comment: Hmmm... I think there could be a problem though. I read `\matrix[matrix of shapes,row sep=1cm,column sep=1cm] {\};` --- notice the single backslash that basically escapes the closing brace. Shouldn't be `{\\}` ?

Comment: ...moreover, I can't find a `matrix of shapes` in the manual (is `matrix of nodes?`? And the link is broken... :-(

Comment: @Rmano You could tell us which post you refer to. After searching for a while, I think you mean the "Knuth shuffle" post. The \\ is fixed, the link leads to a server error on the other side. Maybe it will be fixed there at some time. `matrix of shapes` should be correct with loading `randomgrid`.

Comment: Yep --- that was the post. Yes, probably all these things are defined in `randomgrid`, a pity the link is out. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops.  Another casualty of my moving websites.  Sorry for the bother, but can the link be updated to point to https://github.com/loopspace/Random-Grid

Comment: Found some others that need fixing: http://tex-talk.net/2011/10/i-tex-therefore-ipad/ and http://tex-talk.net/2011/08/great-questions-i-save-your-fingers/ and http://tex-talk.net/2011/10/the-tqft-package/ and http://tex-talk.net/2012/04/voting-up-voting-down/  Thanks!

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks, fixed!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thank you! I still refer to the articles I wrote there from time to time so it's nice to have them properly formatted.